# ViTest Axios mock interceptors issue

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, axios, mocking, vitest

I am trying to add tests for an axios interceptor that refreshes the token on a failed attempt and retries once with a new token.  All tests pass apart from the one I described as: 'should refresh the token and retry the request on a 401 response'.  So I know my interceptors are working as my other tests are passing and I can cause them to fail by changing my assertions.  I can also see console.logs I added in my original function to aid with debugging this.

My onRejected axios mock function fails in the test, it basically serialises the request config I put into it.  It does however work in other tests if used in an expect function:

```
await expect(onRejected(originalRequest)).rejects.toEqual(originalRequest);
```

So in essence I can never try my assertions as the onRejected always fails into the catch block.

Broken test below (I have stripped out the other tests bar one)

```
import axios from 'axios'
import store from '@/store'
import { setupAxios, refreshToken } from '@/services/api/axios'

vi.mock('axios', () => {
  const mockAxiosInstance = vi.fn().mockResolvedValue({ data: 'default response' })
  mockAxiosInstance.get = vi.fn().mockResolvedValue({ data: 'get response' })
  mockAxiosInstance.post = vi.fn().mockResolvedValue({ data: 'post response' })
  mockAxiosInstance.defaults = { headers: { common: {} } }
  mockAxiosInstance.interceptors = {
    response: { use: vi.fn() }
  }

  return {
    default: mockAxiosInstance
  }
})
vi.mock('@/store', () => ({
  default: {
    getters: {
      getCurrentUserData: vi.fn()
    },
    commit: vi.fn()
  }
}))

describe('Axios Setup and Interceptors', () => {
  const onFulfilled = vi.fn()
  const onRejected = vi.fn()

  beforeEach(() => {
    vi.clearAllMocks()
    vi.resetAllMocks()
    axios.interceptors.response.use.mockImplementation((success, error) => {
      onFulfilled.mockImplementation(success)
      onRejected.mockImplementation(error)
    })
    setupAxios()
  })

  it('should refresh the token and retry the request on a 401 response', async () => {
    const originalRequest = {
      url: '/test-endpoint',
      method: 'get',
      headers: {},
      retryRefreshToken: false
    }
    const errorResponse = { config: originalRequest, response: { status: 401 } }

    const newToken = 'updatedBearerToken'
    axios.post.mockResolvedValueOnce({ data: { access: newToken } })
    axios.mockResolvedValueOnce({ data: 'success response' })
    store.getters.getCurrentUserData.mockResolvedValue({ refresh: 'validRefreshToken' })

    // Don't remove the try catch block (without onRejected will fail)
    try {
      // We never reach this point!!  It always goes to the catch block with the errorResponse
      const result = await onRejected(errorResponse)

      expect(store.getters.getCurrentUserData).toHaveBeenCalled()
      expect(axios.post).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/api/token/refresh', { refresh: 'validRefreshToken' })
      expect(axios).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
        expect.objectContaining({
          headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${newToken}` }
        })
      )
      expect(result).toEqual({ data: 'success response' })
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error!', error)
    }
  })

  // Working test
  it('should not retry the request if retryRefreshToken is true', async () => {
    const originalRequest = { config: { retryRefreshToken: true }, response: { status: 401 } }

    await expect(onRejected(originalRequest)).rejects.toEqual(originalRequest)
    expect(axios.post).not.toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
})
```

Function I am testing:

```
const setupAxios = (): void => {
    axios.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = "XMLHttpRequest";
    axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = "csrftoken";
    axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = "X-CSRFToken";
    axios.interceptors.response.use(
        (response) => {
            return response;
        },
        async (error: AxiosError) => {
            const originalConfig: CustomAxiosRequestConfig = error.config;
            // Access Token is expired & retryRefreshToken not set
            if (error.response?.status === 401 && !originalConfig?.retryRefreshToken) {
                // Set retryRefreshToken to true so we don't cause an infinite loop
                originalConfig.retryRefreshToken = true;
                const userData: UserData = await store.getters.getCurrentUserData;
                const refreshTokenString: string = userData.refresh;

                try {
                    // Get new token and retry request
                    if (!refreshTokenString) return Promise.reject(error);
                    const token: string = await refreshToken(refreshTokenString);
                    originalConfig.headers["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${token}`;
                    // Commit to store ()

                    return axios(originalConfig);
                } catch (error) {
                    return Promise.reject(error);
                }
            }
            return Promise.reject(error);
        },
    );
};

const refreshToken = async (refreshToken: string): Promise<string> => {
    try {
        const tokenData = await axios.post("/api/token/refresh", { refresh: refreshToken });
        const newAccessToken: string = tokenData.data.access;

        return newAccessToken;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Failed to refresh token with error:", error);
        throw error;
    }
};
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!